# Admob "House ad" campain for a Interstitial Ad

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

how to set up the Admob "House ad" campain for a Interstitial Ad in order to get allways loaded?

I am getting

```
onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
```

In AdGroup goal I choose "Fully allocate"

but the message keeps coming still!

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interstitials (including house ad interstitials) are set to only serve once per day to each device. This is done so that users don't get spammed with the same interstitial over and over.  You probably received the interstitial once and then couldn't get it again.

If you set up multiple house ad interstitial campaigns, you should be able to get each one once per day on each device.

UPDATE 9/4/2014:

On the new AdMob on apps.admob.com, there is currently no frequency capping on house ads.